# jQuery Like/Unlike issue

Tags: jquery

I have developed a simple like/unlike script.

**Like Script**

```
function like(blog_id,object_id,object_type,user_id,default_count)
{
  if( user_id == 0 ) {
    jQuery("#show_login_box").fancybox({cyclic: true}).trigger('click');
  } else {
           if( default_count == 0 ) {
             var new_count = '1';
             var link = 'unlike(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + new_count + '\')\;';
             jQuery('.likes').html('You like this.');
            } else {
             var new_count = parseInt(default_count) + 1;
               if ( jQuery('.like-user').length ) {
                   var name = jQuery('.like-user').html();
                   var link = 'unlike(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + new_count + '\')\;';
                   jQuery('.likes').html('You and <span class="like-user">'  + name + '</span> likes this.');

               } else {
                   var link = 'unlike(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + new_count + '\')\;';
                   jQuery('.likes').html('You and <span class="like-user"><a href="#">'  + default_count + ' others</a></span> like this.');

               }
            }
             jQuery('.like_click').attr('onclick',link);
             jQuery('.like_click span').html('<img src="/wp-content/plugins/assets/images/icons/unlike-icon.png"> Unlike');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/assets/like.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { object_id: object_id, user_id: user_id, type: 'like', blog_id: blog_id, object_type: object_type, count: default_count },
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data)
        {
             // jQuery('#' + object_id + '_count').html(data.total);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**Unlike Script**

```
function unlike(blog_id,object_id,object_type,user_id,default_count)
{
            if( default_count == 1 ) {
             var not_like = '0';
             var link = 'like(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + default_count + '\',\'' + not_like + '\')\;';
             jQuery('.likes').html('');
            } else {
             var new_count = parseInt(default_count) - 1;
               if ( jQuery('.like-user').length  && default_count > 1 ) {
                   var name = jQuery('.like-user').html();
                   var link = 'like(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + new_count + '\')\;';
                   jQuery('.likes').html('<span class="like-user">'  + name + '</span> like this.');

               } else {
                   var link = 'like(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + new_count + '\')\;';
                   jQuery('.likes').html('<span class="like-user"><a href="#">'  + new_count + ' people</a></span> like this.');

               }
            }
             jQuery('.like_click').attr('onclick',link);
             jQuery('.like_click span').html('<img src="/wp-content/plugins/assets/images/icons/like-icon.png"> Like');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/assets/like.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { object_id: object_id, user_id: user_id, type: 'unlike', blog_id: blog_id, object_type: object_type, count: default_count },
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data)
        {
             // jQuery('#' + object_id + '_count').html(data.total);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="like('85','1','product','1','0');" class="button like_click">
<span><img src="wp-content/plugins/assets/images/icons/like-icon.png"> Like</span>
</a><div class="likes"></div>
```

**Scenario:** I liked a post and im the first one so the message that returned is "You like this." and without refreshing I unliked it and it now removes the "You like this" message. Which is the correct response.

**The Problem:** Without refreshing the same post, I liked it again and now the message appears "You and 1 others like this" instead of "You like this." Message.

**JS Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/z8mKX/2/

I can't configure what's wrong with my script. Please help

Comment: Can you please post a demo and/or the rest of your code (the unlike function is missing)?

Comment: I have included the unlike function.

Comment: I don't see an issue... http://jsfiddle.net/z8mKX/1/ But, I also don't know what the ajax request really does server-side.

Comment: Look this one, http://jsfiddle.net/z8mKX/2/

Comment: Do you need the unlike counts? If not then you could just store a single number (as a number, not string) in your inline click functions and modify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your unlike function, you define `var not_like = '0';` this should be `var new_count = '0';`, and, as Ditmar Wendt mentioned, you're passing the wrong number of arguments to the onclick function, updated code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8mKX/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You have a line,

```
var link = 'like(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + default_count + '\',\'' + not_like + '\')\;';
```

in your unlike function. This sets what should execute when you hit like after you unlike something. You're passing the wrong number of arguments to your "like" function. Remnant of older code?